# How to check for declarations?

Tags: java, string

I am working on a problem where I have List of Strings which is nothing but a java code. So if that code has any declarations before or after method body, then this script should give me an error. If the variable declarations are inside the method body then it should work fine.
for ex:

```
int abcs; // This should generate error.
double cad;  //This should generate error.

Void main(){
  int test;   //This should not generate error.

  void test1(){
    int test3;   //This should not generate error.
   }
}
```

I have wrote a small program for this but could not able to get the desired results, My code is :

```
private void check( String line)
```

{       int count = 0;
        int flag = 0;

```
    // is there an open brace on the current line
    int bracketpos = line.indexOf('{');
    // is there a close brace on the current line
    int closebracketpos = line.indexOf('}');
    // is there a semicolon on the current line
    int charpos = line.indexOf(';');

    // increment count if there is an open brace
    if(bracketpos>=0 )
        ++count;

    // decrement count if there is a close brace
    if(closebracketpos>=0 )
        --count;

    // if there is an open brace on the current line
    // ...and there's a close brace on the current line
    // ...and there's a semicolon on the current line
    // ...and the number of brackets are balanced (count==0)
    if(bracketpos>=0 && closebracketpos>=0 && charpos>=0 && count==0){
        // if the first semicolon appears after the first close brace
        if(charpos>closebracketpos){
            flag =2;
        }
        else
            // the close brace appears after the semicolon, or neither exist
            flag =0;
    }

    else if (charpos >= 0 && count ==0) {

        flag= 1;
    } 
    else {
    flag = 0;
        // the line does not have a ;,{,}
    }

if(flag!=0)
 {
       //ERROR
 }
}
```

I am passing line by line of my example, so count is keeping record of "{" and "}".

**PROBLEM:** 
I am feeding my example to the check() line by line. And I would like to check whether are there any declarations in the example. But If there are any declarations inside the method body then it is fine, but if there are declarations out side the method body then my check() should prompt/ or give me an error.

Comment: As I added in a comment to a *remarkably* similar question yesterday: find a Java parser to use. Don't start writing your own primitive parser which will be *extremely* brittle.

Comment: If your homework is indeed to build a kind of compiler here, then at least you have to keep track of the structure of the app. You may think about it as a tree: its root node is the method declaration, then in its childs it can have several statements but not the definition of another method (just to *check* this specific case).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It is not a homework, I am creating a script, which i will be applying to the directory of thousand files checking for the declarations in all these files.

Comment: Then use a tool that already does this work for you. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Well that does not make any sense, If that would have been the case, you would have been traveling in stone wheels just like early man used to do, instead of rubber wheels/tires.

But ya thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented and finally got it working, The only problem was count was initialized to 0 every time check() is called.

So I came up with two alternatives, either make count static global int. 
Or pass the count value with check() and updated count should be returned so as to keep the record of the "{" and "}".

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong. You should add comments describing what the code does at each stage. Here's to get you started...

```
private void check( String line)
{       int count = 0;
        int flag = 0;

        // is there an open brace on the current line
        int bracketpos = line.indexOf('{');
        // is there a close brace on the current line
        int closebracketpos = line.indexOf('}');
        // is there a semicolon on the current line
        int charpos = line.indexOf(';');

        // increment count if there is an open brace
        if(bracketpos>=0 )
            ++count;

        // decrement count if there is a close brace
        if(closebracketpos>=0 )
            --count;

        // if there is an open brace on the current line
        // ...and there's a close brace on the current line
        // ...and there's a semicolon on the current line
        // ...and the number of brackets are balanced (count==0)
        if(bracketpos>=0 && closebracketpos>=0 && charpos>=0 && count==0){
            // if the first semicolon appears after the first close brace
            if(charpos>closebracketpos){
                flag =2;
            }
            else
                // the close brace appears after the semicolon, or neither exist
                flag =0;
        }

        else if (charpos >= 0 && count ==0) {

            flag= 1;
        } 
        else {
        flag = 0;
            // the line does not have a ;,{,}
        }

  if(flag!=0)
{
        //ERROR
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your changes, but could you explain how is the logic wrong.
 with the count I am able to keep the record of the "{ and }".

Also with the third IF statement, I am able to check for statements like these "{ int a; } double test;" - So this would generate the error.

Comment: I don't think you understand how Java works. You're using local variables which get reset each time the function is called. Also none of the lines have open brace, close brace and semicolon on one line so the if statement is pointless.

Comment: As far as local variables are concerned, How about if I use static int count? I guess that should work.

And lines with open brace,close brace and semicolon is just dealing with the worst case. Because I am not sure about the file contents, so this one act as a worst case handler.